# Bluetooth Server and BroadCastReceiver

Tags: android

My application holds an open bluetooth server socket with a specific `UUID`, in order for another device to connect and transfer files. I'm a bit confused regarding the `BroadcastReceiver`.

In my class which extends `Activity`, I want to check the state of the bluetooth adapter. But my BroadcastReceiver is never triggered. I tried using the BroadcastReceiver this way:

```
public class MainClass extends Activity {
  public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
  super.onCreate(b);
  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
  registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}

private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            Log.w("BroadcastReceiver:  ", "Inside!");

            if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
                final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
                switch (state) {
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                    Log.d("Bluetooth Receiver", "State-off");
                    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                    Log.d("Bluetooth Receiver", "State turning off");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                    Log.d("Bluetooth Receiver", "State-on");
                    btCom = new BluetoothCommunicator(MainClass.this, lastCases, nist);
                    btCom.startServer();
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                    Log.d("Bluetooth Receiver", "State turning on");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };

}
```

I have a question regarding the states:

- The state **STATE_ON** is this only fired off when the bluetooth is turned on during runtime? Or can I start my application with bluetooth turned on, and this event will be fired off? Cause I want to start the method `btCom.startServer()` if bluetooth is turned on

I also read that I need to register the broadcast receiver in my Manifest file, how can I do so if the BroadcastReceiver is in a class which extends Activity? If I had this BroadcastReceiver in a separate class I would do it like this

Say for instace that my Package Name was `com.workbench` and my Class name was `BluetoothReceiver`

The Manifest would look something like this:

```
 <receiver android:name="com.workbench.BluetoothReceiver"></receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

The broadcast action `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED` is sent when the state of the bluetooth adapter changes. You will only see this when the state of the adapter is changed.

You can check the current state of the bluetooth adapter by calling `BluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()`.

You only need to register the `BroadcastReceiver` in your manifest if you want to get the broadcast `Intent` when your application is not running. The way you have implemented the `BroadcastReceiver` (as an anonymous class) it isn't possible to register it in the manifest.